# Render a point in Same Value into Line chart | flutter chart

Tags: flutter, charts

i have some problem with flutter chart, to be precise is in line chart.

the data would not be printed in the chart when the value is same.
this problem is not just affected to the same value, but on zero value in the middle of data too. the zero value was printed in the chart, but it will create weird line. so, i use nulls to change the zero.

do you have a solution for me ? T_T

[same value wasn't showing point/dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POWdp.png)

Comment: Can you please share some code snippets? what you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks for your reply. my problem is have done. i do indexOf to populate the data. so, if the data has same value. they will be merge automatically.